# Hyperledger Composer query with LIMIT and SKIP return all results

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Actually I want to list transactions with a limit, but the query return all the result on REST SERVER API , bellow my query

```
query list {
  description: "List  with limit and offset"
  statement:
      SELECT org.acme.biznet.things
          LIMIT _$limitParam
            SKIP _$skipParam
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, LIMIT/SKIP support is blocked by Fabric presently as described in Issue 1015 on GitHub.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1015

Answer (score -1):

As of Hyperledger Fabric v1.3, pagination of query results is supported. A more efficient approach than skip/limit is utilized. Please see the [pagination documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_as_state_database.html#couchdb-pagination).