# couchdb hyperledger skip/limit problems

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

Using Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js and CouchDb as state database

```
stub.getQueryResult(queryString)
```

where queryString is stringified

```
queryString.selector = {};
queryString.selector.docType = docType;

if (!userId) {
    queryString.selector.userId = {'$gte': "0"};
} else {
    queryString.selector.userId = userId;
}

if (sortBy && sortOrder) {
    queryString.use_index = "_design/indexUserIdDoc";
    queryString.sort=[{}];
    queryString.sort[0][sortBy] = sortOrder;            
}

queryString.skip = 1;
queryString.limit = 1;
```

Everything works fine, but **skip** and **limit** are being ignored;
This example returns more than 1 rows!
Why?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544653/hyperledger-composer-query-with-limit-and-skip-return-all-results There is a

Comment: Yes! Thank you!